# Bash - rsync exclude keeps copying directory

Tags: bash, rsync

I've tried about a dozen different syntax methods and just can't get it.

I'm trying to exclude a directory called 
    **/Users/dirk/Documents/Virtual\ Machines.localized/**

Here is my command:

```
rsync -vzapogDt --delete --exclude-from /Users/dirk/Documents/* ~dirk/ /Volumes/share-1/backup/mbp.20160131
```

When run it continues to copy everything under Documents.  First time posting here, so apologies if I haven't followed protocol.  Believe me, I've researched for a while to no avail.

Cheers

Comment: In your problem statement, you say you want to exclude the `Virtual\ Machines.localized` subdirectory, but in the code you use a wildcard `*`.  Do you want to exclude just this one subdirectory or all subdirectories in `Documents`?

Comment: I only want to exclude the Virtual Machines directory.  I picked Documents during one of my many iterations...  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rsync -vzapogDt --delete --exclude=/Users/dirk/Documents/ ~dirk/ /Volumes/share-1/backup/mbp.20160131
```

From `man rsync`:

> `--exclude-from=FILE`: read exclude patterns from FILE
>
> `--exclude=PATTERN`: exclude files matching PATTERN

Comment: I think the point of `--exclude` is that you can use wildcards.

Comment: @e0k: Yes, then I assume the pattern should be quoted.

Comment: I thought the same.  If you don't use the `=` in the option, you'd definitely need quotes.  But if it's a part of the option like `--exclude=*` it wouldn't be expanded.  (Unless maybe you had file names that started with `--exclude=`.)

Comment: +1 It's unclear exactly what criteria the OP wants to exclude (i.e. a specific subdirectory or all subdirectories), but I agree with using `--exclude=` for a pattern (such as the wildcard in the original command) instead of `--exclude-file=`.  I think the problem the OP had was picking the right option and using proper escapement.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work:   **Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/.localized/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/caches/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/caches/screenshots/**

Answer (score 1):

rsync can't handle absolute or relative paths.... try

```
rsync -vzapogDt --delete --exclude Documents ~dirk/ /Volumes/share-1/backup/mbp.20160131
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cyrus has the right idea: use the `--exclude=<pattern>` option instead of `--exclude-file`.  Try:

```
rsync -vzapogDt --delete --exclude '/Users/dirk/Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/*' ~dirk/ /Volumes/share-1/backup/mbp.20160131
```

The pattern is in single quotes to prevent expansion of the wildcard.  (You want to give the asterisk to `rsync`, not expand it in the shell.)  This also deals with the space in the directory name without backslash escaping.

Comment: Well, I tried this command and here is what I'm seeing:  `Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/caches/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Linux Mint 17.3.vmwarevm/caches/screenshots/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows 10 x64.vmwarevm/
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows 10 x64.vmwarevm/Virtual Disk-s001.vmdk
Documents/Virtual Machines.localized/Windows 10 x64.vmwarevm/Virtual Disk-s002.vmdk`  @Cyrus @e0k